# About Payment Method Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using payment method that is returning following response:

```
{
  "TxnMessage": "Transaction Failed",
  "RespTime": "2020-06-13 12:24:55",
  "BankRefNo": "SITTest6581075080681879",
  "AuthCode": "",
  "TxnStatus": "1",
  "IssuingBank": "HostSim",
  "TxnID": "SITTest6581075080681879",
  "HashValue2": "6b27371a3aaedf7b14d0121aab9eb264791a1bc86bd65a5a18d6d6896de438e5",
  "HashValue": "d48c795d65c1a119bacf67ad4220b2cf6d6c76ef4d3f545fe470833d3180505c",
  "CurrencyCode": "MYR",
  "Amount": "1.00",
  "OrderNumber": "Test6581075080681879",
  "PaymentID": "Test6581075080681879",
  "ServiceID": "SIT",
  "PymtMethod": "CC",
  "TransactionType": "SALE"
}
```

I am using EGHL Flutter plugin. I want to get 'TxnMessage' out of this response.For example in this case I want to show message that your transaction is failed.

My code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:eghl_plugin_unofficial/eghl_plugin_unofficial.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class Payment extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PaymentState createState() => _PaymentState();
}

class _PaymentState extends State<Payment> {
  String _result = 'Awaiting results';
  MyClass myClass;

  Future<void> pay() async {
    try {
      String paymentId = await Eghlpluginunofficial.generateId('Test');

      String result = await Eghlpluginunofficial.makePayment(
        merchantReturnUrl: 'SDK',
        serviceId: 'SIT',
        password: 'sit12345',
        merchantName: 'GHL ePayment Testing',
        amount: 1.00,
        paymentDescription: 'eGHL Payment testing',
        customerName: 'Somebody',
        customerEmail: 'somebody@somesite.com',
        customerPhone: '60123456789',
        paymentId: paymentId,
        orderNumber: paymentId,
        currencyCode: 'MYR',
        languageCode: 'EN',
        pageTimeout: Duration(
          minutes: 12,
          seconds: 30,
        ),
        transactionType: 'SALE',
        paymentMethod: 'ANY',
        useDebugPaymentUrl: true,
      );

      setState(() {
        _result = result;
      });

      print(_result);

    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      setState(() {
        _result = 'PlatformException: ${err.toString()}';
      });
    } catch (err) {
      setState(() {
        _result = 'Error: ${err.toString()}';
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: pay,
                child: Text('Click me to launch payment'),
              ),
              Text(_result),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, You got this sorted out ?

Comment: yes i have solve

Comment: if you are willing to share more, let me know how to contact you. I am trying to integrate flutter payment with my App

Answer (score 0):

```
import package:dart.io;

var jsonData = json.decode(_result);
String txnMessage = jsonData['TxnMessage'];
print(txnMessage);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly get the result as single String instead the response will be form Map.
You first need to decode the response then call the particular field that you want to access.

```
final response =  await Eghlpluginunofficial.makePayment(
    merchantReturnUrl: 'SDK',
    serviceId: 'SIT',
    password: 'sit12345',
    merchantName: 'GHL ePayment Testing',
    amount: 1.00,
    paymentDescription: 'eGHL Payment testing',
    customerName: 'Somebody',
    customerEmail: 'somebody@somesite.com',
    customerPhone: '60123456789',
    paymentId: paymentId,
    orderNumber: paymentId,
    currencyCode: 'MYR',
    languageCode: 'EN',
    pageTimeout: Duration(
      minutes: 12,
      seconds: 30,
    ),
    transactionType: 'SALE',
    paymentMethod: 'ANY',
    useDebugPaymentUrl: true,
  );
```

Then decode it using the convert library of the dart. It will give a decoded json, where you can access that particular field.

```
final decodedJson = jsonDecode(response);
final String TxnMessage = decodedJson['TxnMessage'];
print(TxnMessage);
```

It should give you the desired results. That's how basically the serialization and deserialization of json works.
'
If you want to get more information, you can check out the link: [Json and Serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#:~:text=Basic%20JSON%20serialization%20in%20Flutter,implements%20a%20simple%20user%20model.&text=With%20dart%3Aconvert%20%2C%20you%20can,JSON%20model%20in%20two%20ways.)